# CLion -- Release build causing linker errors

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, clion

I have a `.cpp` file and a corresponding `.h` inside a project in CLion like so:

`element.h`

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

enum class Element
{
    H, He,
    Li, Be, B, C, N, O, F, Ne,
    Na, Mg, Al, Si, P, S, Cl, Ar,
    K, Ca
};

class ElementHash
{
// simple hash function in operator()
};

// LINE IN QUESTION:
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Element& e);

struct ElementData
{
};

extern const std::unordered_map<std::string, Element> elementObjectLookupTable;
extern const std::unordered_map<Element, ElementData, ElementHash> elementDataLoopkupTable;

std::string toString(const Element& e);
```

`element.cpp`

```
#include "element.h"

using namespace std;


ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const Element& e)
{
    out << toString(e);
    return out;
}

// rest of the file's not important
```

These two files (along with others) are all built from a subdirectory into a `.dylib` which is then linked to the executable built by the main project. This `.dylib` builds and links just fine under the Debug build, but when I switch to release build in the IDE, I get the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& std::__1::operator<<<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, Element const&) in element.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [/Users/_____/ClionProjects/chemhelp/bin/Release/libchemhelp-core.dylib] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/chemhelp-core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/chemhelp-core.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [chemhelp-core] Error 2
```

I don't know if I've broken something in my project or in the settings, but for some reason the Release build is failing.

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks like your library was compiled with a different architecture and/or build settings than the other code in your project.

Of course, try cleaning the project first.

You may need to configure your project such that:

- In your debug build, you compile the library and the main with debug settings the same, and link with the same version of the standard C++ library.
- Similarly in release, the library and main code should be using the same release flags and link against the same version of the standard C++ libraries.

Comment: In the "Edit Configurations" settings dialog I set "Build All" to "Release", "chemhelp" (the executable) to "Release", and "chemhelp-core" (the dylib) to "Release". I'm still getting the same linker error. When I set all 3 to "Debug" I get no errors however.

Comment: I'd still double check the C++ standard library version for each of the components in the release settings.  Also check all the optimization flags, etc.   Most of the time I've seen these oddities it's been mismatched settings between the library and the executable linking against that library...

Comment: You may have to check your CMake file to ensure that your libraries and build settings are consistent between the various components for both release and debug builds.